# Select/Deselect all checkbox elements AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have a list of items in AngularJS with checkboxes and I have a checkbox that can select all items. The function is implemented only to select all items and what I want is to modify it to also deselect all items.

This is my function:

```
$scope.items.allItemsSelected = false;
$scope.selectAll = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.itemsList.length; i++) {
        $scope.temp.push($scope.itemsList[i].name);
        console.log($scope.itemsList[i].name);
        $scope.itemsList[i].isChecked = $scope.items.allItemsSelected;
    }
};
```

This is my html :

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="items.allItemsSelected"
             ng-change="selectAll()">
    Select all
</md-checkbox>
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to modify this to also deselect elements ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example of array `$scope.itemsList` and the `ngRepeat` in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-checked attributes.

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="items.allItemsSelected" ng-change="selectAll()">
    Select all
</md-checkbox>
```

checkbox1--

```
<md-checkbox ng-checked="isSelectAll" ng-model="items.allItemsSelected" ng-change="selectAll()">
    Select all
</md-checkbox>
```

checkbox2--

```
<md-checkbox ng-checked="isSelectAll" ng-model="items.allItemsSelected" ng-change="selectAll()">
    Select all
</md-checkbox>
```

JS:

```
$scope.isSelectAll = false;
$scope.selectAll = function() {
    if (!$scope.isSelectAll) {
        $scope.isSelectAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.isSelectAll = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `ngChecked` directive should not be used together with `ngModel`, as this can lead to unexpected behavior: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: when i deselect all items i want to empty my array

Comment: When you deselecting all,  put your array  $scope.itemsList =[ ] in else condition of selectAll function.

Comment: i tried your solution but it does not allow me to check the select all button